# Google Sheets API: Append cells and add developer metadata atomically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to append a row of cells to a google sheet and also attach some developer metadata to that row.

In the Google Sheets v4 API, I know you can use [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to append a row with the [appendCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AppendCellsRequest) request, and you can add developer metadata using the [createDeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#CreateDeveloperMetadataRequest) request.

My issue is that I wanna set some developer metadata to specifically the newly appended cells atomically. There's not really a way to specifically ensure the range of the newly added row in `createDeveloperMetadata`, and if I use two different requests, someone else may insert a row between those requests which could shift all the rows, causing the appended cell's range to be pointing to an incorrect row.

Is there a way to attach developer metadata to a newly added cell *atomically*?

Comment: From your question, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about them, can I ask you about the detail of them? And also, can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is not currently way of ensuring that the sheet structure hasn't changed between requests.*

#### More Information:

Your The best option, I think, is to make two sequential requests in the same batch. Though this isn't foolproof, in very unlucky circumstances. Even inserting the row directly using an `UpdateCellsRequest` isn't foolproof either, as simply knowing which row you inserted the data doesn't exclude the possibility that someone else may insert/delete a row before it between the two requests.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for the Sheets API and that you would like to request they implement it. Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services.

The page to file a Feature Request for the Google Sheets API is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917).

#### References:

- [Requests - UpdateCellsRequest | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [Requests - AppendCellsRequest | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AppendCellsRequest)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I figured out was essentially:

- Fetch the dimensions of the sheet
- Perform a batch update with `insertDimension`, `updateCells`, and `createDeveloperMetadata` all performed for the same sheet dimension index at the end of the sheet

This basically ensures that the dimension index will point to the same row for all 3 operations in the batch update, and if the index points out of bounds, all 3 operations will fail